# Angular 8 : observable.pipe() not working anymore?

Tags: angular, observable, angular8

I'm just upgrading my application from Angular 7 to Angular 8.
One of my methods doesn't seems to work anymore since the migration. On an Observable (from a HTTP POST), I want to perform some actions through a .pipe().

The caller can so execute a .subscribe() on the returned Observable.

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable {
    const url =  `${this.baseUrl}/oauth/token`;
    const body = `username=${encodeURIComponent(username)}&password=${encodeURIComponent(password)}&grant_type=password`;

    return this.http.post(url, body, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe( map(value => {
        console.info('Succeed');
        return of(true);
      }));
  }
```

Unfortunately, the map seems not be executed anymore (no log in the console).

Anybody to help me to find a way to fix it ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding `.pipe(catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {}`?

Comment: by the way, why u want to do that?

Comment: Yes, There's no error. The caller receives the response of the http request...

Comment: My purpose is to perform some actions and convert the HTTP response to return a "formated" value (instead of a HTTP response OAUTH2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Mapping operating with value which observable returns so, here is the first thing you should change, I think:

```
return this.http.post(url, body, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe( map(value => {
        console.info('Succeed');
        return of(true); // Here is an error. Don't use `of`.
      }));
```

2. Pipeable operators still working. So, there could be an error in your HTTP request. Consider rewrite it as follows and check for the error logs:

```
return this.http.post(url, body, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe( 
         map(value => {
           console.info('Succeed');
           return true;
         }),
         catchError(err => {
           console.error('HTTP ERROR: ', err);
           return throwError(err);
         })
       );
```

3. I've noticed, that you're using `info` action (`console.info('Succeed');`). Check the debug level of you dev tools logs

Comment: When I use your code, it's working well, and no error is logged in the console. But if I only remove the catchError, it doesn't work anymore. I don't understand why, because there's no error in the HTTP call....

Anyway, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

The map operator that you are using is used to map raw/primitive values.

Eg: you can take a string, and return an number, or take an object and return another object.

It will not however unwrap a returned observable, for that you would need to use a `switchMap` (ref: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html)

In this case there is no need to use a `switchMap`, simply returning `true` rather than `of(true)` should help.

On the calling code side, make sure you remember to subscribe to the observable returned from `login`, or the http request will never be made.

Comment: Thanks for the details about map & switchMap. I'm quite new in Angular (it's a learning project), so it's possible I don't take the right way